# Prevent variables from being rewritten in Makefiles?

Tags: makefile

I'm learning about Makefiles and application cross-compiling, and I'd like to find a way to prevent variables from being redefined in Makefiles further down the chain.

As an example, I write a top-level Makefile /usr/src/someapp.mk that will...

1) download the application's source code from the web into /usr/src/someapp-1.2.3/

2) untar the source, and

3) run its original /usr/src/someapp-1.2.3/Makefile

Since the original Makefile was written as a stand-alone script, it will unknowningly (re)define the usual suspects (CC, AR/RANLIB, etc.) with local values, effectively erasing the value I chose in the top-level Makefile:

```
#My top-level /usr/src/someapp.mk:
all:
    wget someapp-1.2.3.tar.gz
    tar xzvf someapp-1.2.3.tar.gz
    cd someapp-1.2.3 && $(MAKE)

#Original Makefile from www /usr/src/someapp-1.2.3/Makefile:
#RANLIB locally redefined... :-/
RANLIB=ranlib

all:
    $(RANLIB)...
```

I'd like users to be able to download the original source code instead of providing my own, modified version: Is there a way to have "make" either ignore when variables are redefined locally or rewrite them on the fly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?=` operator will only define a variable if it is unset.

```
VAR ?= value
```

By far the most useful way though is to define variables on the make command line. Such variables become read-only for the duration of the make.

```
$ cat Makefile
VAR := hello
$(error [${VAR}])
```

then

```
$ make
Makefile:2: *** [hello].  Stop.
```

but

```
$ make VAR='value overridden'
Makefile:2: *** [value overridden].  Stop.
```

This suggests your snippet `cd someapp-1.2.3 && $(MAKE)` becomes `$(MAKE) -C someapp-1.2.3 RANLIB=myval`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll experiment with ?=

Comment: Overridden unless updated with the `override` directive, in GNU Make at least.

Answer (score 1):

Make variables passed through make command line override makefile assignments. http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Override-Directive

Invoke that third-party makefile as follows:

```
$ make ... RANLIB=myranlib CC=mycc
```